# Google Sheets pivot table won't show totals for more than one Row item

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

[Here's a link to the original sheet read only.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaGu5Cd0kRPKy0v-EaVxgfnUxaxWlgDhfhfgRQy6hrc/edit?usp=sharing)  The Experiment tab is the one in question.  If you want to play, you need to make your own copy, then share back in your answer.

---

I've got Totals checked or both Common Name and for Pot Description.  Why won't more than one display?  If I move Pot description up, it will total then Common Name won't.

If I untick Common Name totals, there is still no total.

If I delete Common Name, I still don't get totals.

What am I missing?

[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: Please create a demo spreadsheet and share it with anyone with the link to view only. Why? Maybe the issue can't be reproducible i.e. there is problem with the spreadsheet / sheet, by the other hand, the screenshot doesn't show enough details. Anyway, this looks to be like a troubleshooting type question which are not a good fit for most SE sites (but you might talk about this on the general chat or create a specific chat room)

Comment: I have added a link.  Also, if this isn't a good fit, please mark for closing, or just delete it.

Comment: I made a copy of the link spreadsheet, the sheet totals works fine on the copy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "Values" into your pivot table. Then select the field you'd like to total. In this case it is "Price". Summary by "sum". It will open a new column and display your totals.